# D3 histogram brushing specific datapoints

Tags: d3.js

I'm a bit new to D3, so I apologize if this is trivial.

I want to create a histogram that allows a user to brush over parts of a histogram and display all of the selected data points in a table separate of the histogram. Basically, I want to create (http://square.github.com/crossfilter/) in D3 using a "brush". All of the examples that I've seen have bar charts instead of histograms. I couldn't get anything to work by creating the brush in a histogram visualization. Is this possible or should I just re-tool a bar graph into a pseudo-histogram?

Thank you!